# Boto on visual studio

Tags: python, visual-studio, amazon-web-services

How do I configure boto with Visual Studio 2010. Please help.

I have extracted the boto directory on my system. Using this link https://github.com/boto/boto

Just copy pasting the directory into the python23 folder did not help either.

I would appreciate your help.

Comment: Did you follow the installation instructions in the [README](https://github.com/boto/boto/blob/develop/README.rst)?

Comment: yes made the changes as given in README. It works fine now. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this command

```
"python <<path to setup.py>> install"
```